# getting problem in inserting values in microseconds

Tags: cassandra

I am inserting in time using timestamp datatype but it cannot give me values in microseconds. Is it possible to insert values in microseconds or it takes values only up to milliseconds.

```
cqlsh:cassandradb> select * from time_stamp;

 id | name    | t
----+---------+---------------------------------
  1 | deepank | 2015-02-16 06:30:24.000000+0000
  2 |    arun | 2016-02-16 06:35:24.483000+0000
```

this is what I have inserted but I am not expecting this value. I have simply inserted value in milliseconds when I insert in micro it gives me error as following
    (2 rows)
    cqlsh:cassandradb> select id, name, blobAsBigint(timestampAsBlob(t)) from time_                                                                          stamp;

```
 id | name    | system.blobasbigint(system.timestampasblob(t))
----+---------+------------------------------------------------
  1 | deepank |                                  1424068224000
  2 |    arun |                                  1455604524483
```

(2 rows)
In this, I have used blob but I think it didn't go well.

```
cqlsh:cassandradb> insert into time_stamp(id,name, t)values(3,'tarun','2015-02-16 06:30:2.84325');
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unable to coerce '2015-02-16 06:30:2.84325' to a formatted date (long)"

cqlsh:cassandradb> insert into time_stamp(id,name, t)values(3,'tarun','2015-02-16 06:30:2.8432');
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unable to coerce '2015-02-16 06:30:2.8432' to a formatted date (long)"

cqlsh:cassandradb> insert into time_stamp(id,name, t)values(3,'tarun','2015-02-16 06:30:2.842');``
last value is taken
```

I expect that it could insert value in microseconds;
so that output will be in six digit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timestamp in Cassandra has millisecond resolution, and you should use only 3 digits after `.` in timestamp string. The microsecond resolution is used only for WriteTime of the record.

For some, unknown for me, reason, `cqlsh` outputs data with microseconds resolution, and imho it's huge UX problem with it...

Comment: but if want to select i particular time how we can do it.

Comment: just as usual: `select ... from table where t = '2015-02-16 06:30:24.000+0000';`

Comment: yeah, i tried but it'st working it did not take '0+0000' .it says its too long to read.

Comment: Hmmm - it just works for me: `create table test(t timestamp primary key);`, `insert into test(t) values('2019-06-18 03:03:05.000+0000');`, `select * from test where t = '2019-06-18 03:03:05.000+0000';` gives me 1 row...