# cqlsh.py COPY FROM cannot parse timestamp

Tags: cassandra, copy, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh

Below is my date format which is default %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z

```
| updateddate                     |
| 2017-01-13 16:23:26.580000+0000  |
```

Still, when I am trying to import(with COPY command) it is throwing below error.

```
Failed to import 1 rows: ParseError - Failed to parse  2017-01-09 17:51:57.227000+0000  : can't interpret ' 2017-01-09 17:51:57.227000+0000 ' as a date with format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z or as int,  given up without retries
```

Cassandra version: 3.11.0
Server : Ubuntu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting problem in inserting values in microseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55808237/getting-problem-in-inserting-values-in-microseconds)

Comment: Well, the issue was there is space in date. which was not matching the date format.